# How to use jquery real person in view mvc razor asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have use jQuery Real Person at `keith-wood.name/realPerson.html`. However, after config and test, It's not work.As follow is snippet code in view.Look so it's ok, show capcha

[image]

```js
    $('.realperson_text').realperson({
        length: 6,
        chars: $.realperson.alphanumeric
});
```

```html
  <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
                    <h5>Capcha</h5>
                    <div class="realperson_text"></div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.defaultReal, new { @class = "form-control text-uppercase", @placeholder = "type capcha code", @maxlength = "6" })
 </div>
```

And this is action, snippet code

```
public ActionResult UploadProfile(TestModel capcha_demo)
{
        var salt = 12345;   
        if (rpHash(capcha_demo.defaultReal + salt) != Request.Form["realPersonHash"])
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Capcha wrong";
        }
}
```

Yep, as demo in home page, I don't known what is the `Request.Form["realPersonHash"]`.
Can you tell me how to get it ?

Comment: This is kind of an obscure library. You'll most likely need to take it up with the developer to get a real answer. However, you'd be best served by using something a little more standard and tried-and-true like Google's ReCAPTCHA (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html). It's stupidly simple to implement, but you'll have a wealth of community support if you do have issues. And, even better, it only requires a simple click by the user rather than having to type of string of letters and numbers.

Comment: if you put a debug point on `var salt = 12345;` what is in the `capcha_demo` parameter? maybe the `realPersonHash` is in there?

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that even those text-based CAPTCHAs where even *you* can't make out the text can be defeated by bots over 90% of the time. Google famously broke their own old CAPTCHA by open-sourcing an unrelated text-detection API used for street view. The CAPTCHA you have here looks incredibly easy for a bot to decipher.

Comment: Dear @Noctane , you should read clearly in C# code

Comment: As Chris Pratt is saying I would go with google re-captcha as well, but it may also be important for you to learn how to fix the issue you have currently.

Comment: #Chris Pratt , thank for your reply, I'll try it but first , i still test this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick this plugin use it's to add an element before form submit.

In plugin code jquery.realperson.js line 112 you have this code:

```
on('submit.' + inst.name, function() {
                var name = inst.options.hashName.replace(/\{n\}/, elem.attr('name'));
                var form = $(this);
                form.find('input[name="' + name + '"]').remove();
                form.append('<input type="hidden" class="' + self._hashClass + '" name="' + name +
                    '" value="' + hash(text + salt) + '">');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    form.find('input[name="' + name + '"]').remove();
                }, 0);
            });
```

You can see that it add an input (form.append), and delete it just after the submit

```
form.find('input[name="' + name + '"]').remove();
```

That's all the trick!

Comment: No, it depend on your input

Comment: Oh, sure , when i open devtool in Chrome , i see `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="defaultReal" an98ck Content-Disposition: form-data; name="undefinedHash" -1524496973` . I think i should try as follow `if (rpHash(capcha_demo.defaultReal + salt) != Request.Form["undefinedHash"])` in this case. How about you ?

Comment: Did you fill data in input text?

Comment: Yes, data in capcha as "AN98CK" , then i type in input text "an98ck" .But run it get Capcha wrong. What's happen ?

Comment: Oh, i get error , I think don't need salt , It's ok as `if (rpHash(capcha_demo.defaultReal) != Request.Form["undefinedHash"])`